# Pass a variable array to a macro

Tags: variable, macro

I try to pass a variable from to a macro:

```
{% set syName = {
   x: { name: "Schön"},
   y: { name: "Leicht bewölkt"},
   z: { name: "Stark Bewölkt"},
    } 
%}

{% macro prognose(symbol, syName) %}
   <img src="test/{{ symbol }}.png">
   {% for alt in syName %}
      {{ alt.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.prognose(  '1' , syName ) }}
```

So far so good. But this passes all the content from the variable into the macro. I want to trigger x, y, z individually.

So I tried to write it like this: `{{ _self.prognose(  '1' , syName.x ) }}`

This gives the error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a string variable
>   ("Schön")

How do I have to write this?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `_self` like that... Per the docs: ["When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it, you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input() instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in Twig 2.x."](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) Even though the macro is in the same file, you still need to `import` it.

Comment: I plan on placing all macros in a separate file later on.  So I need write an import tag between the macro and the call to the macro? Something like this? `{% macro bla( greetings ) %}{{ greetings }}{% endmacro %}{% import 'bla' as this %}{{ this.bla(  'hello' ) }}`

Comment: Yup, exactly. So something like `{% import _self as myMacros %}`, then you could call it like `{{ myMacros.prognose('1', syName) }}`. In fact, when you move it to a separate file, you'll need that `import` anyway. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example makes sense because you are passing a multidimensional  array (`syName`), looping through that array, assigns each array within to `alt` allowing you to then access the values through dot notation (`{{ alt.name }}`), because `alt` is an array.

In your second example you are passing through just one array, so when you loop through it, the value in `name` is assigned to `alt` as a string. (the value in the array) so you can echo it out just by doing `{{ alt }}`

So your code could look like:

```
{% macro prognose(symbol, syName) %}
   <img src="test/{{ symbol }}.png">
   {% for name in syName %}
      {{ name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.prognose(  '1' , syName.x ) }}
```

This will output `Schön`

To make things even easier for yourself, if you are passing just one array i.e `syName.x` You don't even need the loop as you can just access the value through dot notation:

```
{% set syName = {
   x: { name: "Schön"},
   y: { name: "Leicht bewölkt"},
   z: { name: "Stark Bewölkt"},
}%}

{% macro prognose(symbol, syName) %}
    <img src="test/{{ symbol }}.png">
    {{ syName.name }} 
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.prognose('1', syName.x) }}
```

This will output `Schön`

Comment: Thank you. The one with the for loop works now. But you simplified code doesn't. It throws: `Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("")`

Comment: That would happen if the value of the array being passed to the macro is `null`, are you passing calling the macro like `{{ _self.prognose(  '1' , syName.x ) }}` and `syName.x` is not `null`?

Comment: Yep exactly. But the value of `x` is not not `null`, its `Schön`.

Comment: That's bizarre, I've just updated that part of my answer to show the full code i'm using, which is working....can you confirm this is the same as yours?

Comment: I copied your code 1:1 and it works. There must be a typo or something in my extended code. I just can't see it right now. But your code is correct.